# Why have Network Error on https apisauce call

Tags: react-native, expo, apisauce

I have an expo react native app that works fine with apisauce and http connection but when i set a https baseurl it shows me network-error but on postman the same call works fine.

[error example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSSq5.png)

```
const apiClient = create({
  baseURL: settings.apiUrl,
  headers: {
    Accept: "*/*",
    Host: "my-domain.com",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    Connection: "keep-alive",
  },
  timeout: 30000,
});
```

and in settings.apiUrl = `apiUrl: "https://my-domain.com",`